# Load additional history in tmux scrollback

Tags: tmux, scrolling

If I'm monitoring log output in tmux and see something that I want to inspect as it scrolls by, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>. I can then move around in the scroll buffer. When I am finished, I go to the end of the scroll buffer, but it only shows what was the last thing logged to the console before I entered copy mode. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to leave copy mode, then the window jumps to the current place in the log, and it's very hard for me to determine what was skipped. Is there a way to "refresh" the scroll buffer while I'm in copy mode?

Note: This question is not about increasing the size of the scroll buffer (which is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/how-to-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux/18777877#18777877). It is about updating the contents of the scroll buffer without leaving copy mode.

Comment: This has been answered in the following already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18777877/3948553

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answer is on http://stackoverflow.com/a/18777877/3948553

Comment: I've added clarification. Those questions are about increasing the size of the scroll buffer. This is about updating the scroll buffer when tmux pauses it while you're in copy mode.

Comment: This question is much more on-topic here than it is on [SO]. Even if it were equally on-topic on both sites, the existence of an answer on the other site would not be a reason to close it on this site.

Comment: and P.S. I agree with Tom — this question is not a duplicate of that question, anyway. And I hope people haven't been *down voting* this perfectly clear question just because they believe that it has already been answered in another community — that's an inappropriate use of a down vote.